# optimization - stepping may behave oddly; variables may not be available in Xcode 9.1

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

When i put debug point in project i get this one error

> App Name was compiled with optimization - stepping may behave oddly;
>   variables may not be available.

And Also i don't get debug point and xcode not print any log.

If anyone know solution please share.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are receiving this message because you set your target's optimization level to one of the `Fast` options.

Set the **Optimization Level** to `None` while debugging to make the message go away and your break points behave normally:

[image]

Comment: @SakirSherasiya What is not working? Do you still see the message?

Comment: @joem i see the same message

Comment: @SakirSherasiya Then your app is still using one of the fast optimization levels somewhere. You can easily reproduce this issue when you create a new project, then set the optimization level to `Fast` -> You get the message. When you set the optimization level to `None` -> The message is gone. The issue is definitely caused by the `Fast` Optimization Level. So somewhere in your app you still use the `Fast` Optimization Level. Also make sure that you set the Optimization Level for the **Swift Compiler** and not **Apple LLVM**

Comment: hello why i didnt see  Optimization Level anywhere in my project? Target - > Build setting?...

Answer (score -2):

I had the same issue and I solve it adding to Apple LLVM - Custom Compiler Flags:

```
Other C Flags: -DRUNTIME_IL2CPP=1
```