# My App doesn't work on the release mode after upgraded to the Xcode 11.4 or later

Tags: ios, xcode, cryptography, xcode11.3, xcode11.4

I've faced an issue when I've updated the Xcode version to 11.4 or later.
The project works fine in the debug mode.

A key pair was created then data signed through the private key and send it to the server. Finally, the server can verify sign data through the public key.

But when I've turned to the release mode the server can't verify signed data anymore.

There is the same private key in both modes.

With this private key, I've switched to the Xcode 11.3 or earlier everything works like a charm and I don't have any idea.

PS: Since my app works on creating a key pair (ECDSA) probably that the part which has to do with sign data doesn't work properly.

I've tried this way, I've set the same value for all properties in both modes (debug and release) but the issue still exists.

Update: If I've known what's different between Xcode 11.3 and 11.4 or later, it's could be helpful.

Please let me know if you need further information.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide more information than "doesn't work".  What messages do you get in the console log?  Does it crash?  What is the exception message?  Does it run but not produce the correct output or behaviour?  If so, show the relevant code.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks for informing, I've added some information, and also, in my opinion, it hasn't to do with the code but if you think it would be better I can add it in foreseeable future.

Comment: @Paulw11Since I've edited my post I guess it takes time to appear. Btw In the debug mode a key pair was created, the sign function works fine and the server verify signed data without any issue but when I turn to the release mode same code same private key and same sign function look like work fine but the server can't verify a signed data.

Comment: I would suggest that you check the optimisation settings in the two Xcode versions; perhaps that is causing your problem.  If you can create a [MCVE] that reproduces the fault it will be easier for people to help you.

Comment: @Paulw11Thanks Paul, I'll check the optimization settings. 
About the minimal reproducible example, I can prepare an empale on the client-side (iPhone) but I have to coordinate with the server-side in order to send the response to the minimal app.
So let me check it and I'll tell you as soon as possible.

Comment: Even if you can create code that works entirely on the phone (ie verify its own signature) it might help debug the problem.  Or you can create an app for yourself that shows the base64 signature you are generating in both cases and compare that with what you get on the server.  There is the possibility for a problem in both the signature generation and the transport code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223613/discussion-between-reza-dehnavi-and-paulw11).

Comment: @Paulw11Please check the chat and you can find a simple app by following the link: 
https://github.com/razor313/signChecker/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the recommendation of @Paulw, I made [a simple app](https://github.com/razor313/signChecker/), and I could reproduce the bug.

So I realized the bug has to do everything with the memory issue.

Finally, with [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47302748/optimization-stepping-may-behave-oddly-variables-may-not-be-available-in-xcod), I could solve it.